# How to make begin and end functions rvalue qualified

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a file parser. Since the user can pass through the file only once I want the iterator to be accessible only from rvalue reference.

```
MyParser parser("/path/to/file");
for(auto it : std::move(parser)){
   // example
   for(auto & [key, value]: it){
      std::court << key << '\t' << value << std::endl;
   }
}
```

So, I did the following

```
class MyParser{

public:
  MaParser(const std::string &path): begin_iterator_(path){}


  //  ====== Begin   iterator class ==============
  class iterator{
    public:
      typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> value_type;

      // Ctor
      iterator(const std::string & path):{
        // Initialize
      }

      // Default ctor
      iterator() = default;
      
      // Move ctor
      iterator(iterator && other){
        istream_ = std::move(other.istream_);
        values_ = std::move(other.value_);
      }

      iterator & operator=(iterator && other){
        istream_ = std::move(other.istream_);
        values_ = std::move(other.value_);
        return *this;
      }

      void operator++(){// definition}

      value_type & operator*(){
        return value_;
      }    
      
      bool operator==(const iterator & other) const {
        return false; // logic here
      }

      bool operator!=(const iterator & other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
      }

    private:
      std::unique_ptr<std::istream> istream_;
      value_type value_;        
  };
    //  ====== End   iterator class ==============

  iterator && begin() &&{
    return std::move(begin_iterator_);
  }

  iterator && end() && {
    return iterator();
  }
private:
  iterator begin_iterator_;
};
```

Now, I can iterate like this:

```
for(auto it = std::move(parser).begin(); it != myParser::iterator(); ++it){

}
```

but when I try to iterate according to the original intention I get an error

`cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'MyParser' to 'MyParser &&'`.

Q1:
How do I solve this problem?

Q2:
If instead of the begin_iterator in the function **begin** do

```
iterator && begin() &&{
    return iterator(path_); // Assuming we stored the path in a local variable.
  }
```

the program crashes on the iterator init `auto it = std::move(parser).begin();` , when trying to move value_ in the move-constructor. Why?

Comment: [OT]: in "`for(auto it : std::move(parser))`", name `it` is misleading, it is not an iterator (seems to be a pair, so `p` would be better)

Comment: You might play with [iterator category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories) through [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range-based for is basically syntax sugar. Your loop of:

```cpp
for (auto it : std::move(parser)) {
    statements;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```cpp
{
    auto && __range = std::move(parser);
    for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), end = __range.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        auto it = *__begin;
        {
            statements;
        }
    }
}
```

So even though `__range` is an rvalue reference, `__range.begin()` still calls `begin` on an lvalue (the rvalue-ness isn't used).

There's no way around this, you cannot make it so that only rvalues can be iterated over in a range-for. For reference, [`std::ranges::istream_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view) does a similar thing and the only thing it does for safety is make its iterator move-only, so what you already have should be enough.

---

For your second question, if you return a temporary from `iterator && begin() &&`, the temporary is destroyed before the function returns and you get a dangling reference. Your current `end` function suffers from the same problem. Simply return by value `iterator begin() &&`. The move from the temporary should be elided.